# Añadir un efecto de transición css a una función JS

Tags: javascript

tengo una función en Js que hace un cambio de pestañas o tabs de contenidos, algo similar a Jquery tabs, pero quisiera saber cómo puedo añadir un efecto de transición o fade in al momento que cambia el contenido y pasa de display none o display block.

dejo el código de la función aquí.

```
function openPage(pageName) {
            // oculta todos los elementos que contengan la clase tabs_content */
            var i, tabcontent;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs_content");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            //muestra un tabs_content especifico
            document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes aplicar animación o transición a la propiedad `display`, pero puedes probar con ancho y alto mínimo de los elementos, junto con opacidad. Adicionalmente, tal vez necesites probar con posición absoluta para que no se vea como que los elementos se empujan, pero ya queda para que lo investigues.

```js
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Solo si el clic fue en un enlace
    if(e.target.tagName == 'A') {
        // Ocultar div activo
        document.querySelector('.divtab.mostrar').classList.remove('mostrar');
        // Obtener ID del div a mostrar
        let id = e.target.href.split('#')[1];
        // Agregar clave al div destino
        document.getElementById(id).classList.add('mostrar');
    }
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.divtab {
    opacity: 0;
    max-width: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.divtab.mostrar {
    opacity: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    /* Asigna este atributo de acuerdo al contenido o contenedor */
    max-height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#div1">Div 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div2">Div 2</a></li>
<ul>
<div id="div1" class="divtab mostrar">Contenido del div 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="divtab">Contenido del div 2</div>
```