# ¿Cómo añadir transacción a un display en css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy desarrollando una web en la cual hay un popup y me gustaría que al abrirse (con js) no apareciese rápido, sino con una animación o transición. Este es mi código.

```
<button onclick="showPopup()" class="button">Empezar</button>

<div class="popup" id="popup">
</div>

<script>
function showPopup(){
document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

El css:

```
.popup{
  display: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  transition: display 1s;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  
}
```

Comment: No se pueden aplicar efectos de transición a la propiedad `display`. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/476130/54039), solo conserva la posición absoluta y debe funcionar como esperas.